# Why does HuggingFace's Bart Summarizer replicate the given input text?

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers, summarization

I am trying to summarize the input text using Bart's pretrained summarization pipeline. However, I am noticing that the generated summary is exactly the same as the text that I am feeding the model to summarize upon. I also tried fine-tuning the model on the text-summary pairs(human-generated summaries), but for new input texts as well, the same input texts are being generated as the output.

I intend my summary to be a gist of the given input text. What methods can I use to resolve this? And, are there any other models which might perform better at generating summaries?

Comment: Put your test case in [here](https://huggingface.co/facebook/bart-large-cnn), if it generate summarization, then debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue with the bart_base model from facebook. I tried a couple other models, and I've found that Sam Shleifer's DistilBART model does really well at summarizing news articles.
If you want to try it out :

```
model = BartForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("sshleifer/distilbart-xsum-6-6")
tokenizer = BartTokenizer.from_pretrained("sshleifer/distilbart-xsum-6-6")
```